# Does libssh supports sftp server functionality?

Tags: c++, c, ssh, libssh

In my project i need to transfer files between a server and multiple clients.
The communication between client and server should be encrypted,
there should be an authentication by username and password
and the protocol should be a common one, so i thought about sftp.

There are two c/c++ libraries for ssh: libssh and libssh2, 
where only the first one provides also server functionality.

There is a API documentation for libssh where the client module, 
involving the submodule [sftp](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__sftp.html), is well documented. 
But for the [server](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__server.html) API I can only find basic ssh functions.

Does libssh provide server side sftp support at all?

Comment: There's also our SecureBlackbox that has SSH and SFTP server components and C++ edition of which can be used to build SFTP server. See http://www.eldos.com/sbb/lib-sftp.php

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. But i need a opensource library.

Comment: @user2369952 did you ever come up with a working code for the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can implement a sftp server using libssh. It just isn't doucmented.

See the functions at the end of the sftp.h file:

http://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/tree/include/libssh/sftp.h

and also

http://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/tree/src/sftpserver.c

We will soon release a new version of libssh with improved server support.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds grade.
Are the functions implemented in sftpserver.c already usable, do I need special compiling options when building the library?

Comment: Any news about SFTP server documentation ?

Comment: Also take a look at:
https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/libssh-svn/blob/master/branches/nonblocking/sftp_server/protocol.c
https://github.com/canonical/multipass/blob/master/src/sshfs_mount/sftp_server.cpp

Answer (score 1):

you can use libssh for sftp. I can put some code here for you which is supporting Pause/Resume and works on windows. I cannot copy the  entire class because it will exceed this website limit. change username and password and hostname  to proper equivalents of your sftp server:

```
    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {

        //Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");


        pSFTPConnector  sshc = new  SFTPConnector(L".\\", L"127.0.0.1", 22, L"iman", L"iman");  // change the hostname , port , username, password to your sftp server, your credentials

        //FILE *nullfile = fopen("null", "w");  
        //sshc->setLogFile(nullfile);
        sshc->setVerbosity(SSH_LOG_RARE);       // you can change the verbosity as appropriate for you

        int i=  sshc->InitSession();
        i=sshc->ConnectSession();
        i = sshc->InitSFTP();


        //i = sshc->SFTPrename("renamed_myfile.txt", "myfile.txt");  //change these file names
        //i = sshc->Makedir("sftpdir");
        //i = sshc->testUploadFile("myfile2.txt", "1234567890testfile");


        // change these file names to whatever appropriate
        //i = sshc->SFTPget("c:\\testdir\\Got_CAR_HIRE_FINAL_test.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL_test.jpg", 64*1024 );  
        i = sshc->SFTPget("c:\\testdir\\get_downloaded_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 *1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPreget("c:\\testdir\\reget_downloaded_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPput("c:\\testdir\\CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "put_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);
        i = sshc->SFTPreput("c:\\testdir\\CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", "reput_CAR_HIRE_FINAL.jpg", 64 * 1024);

        delete sshc;
        return 0;
    }


typedef enum sshconerr{
    E_OK = 1, E_SESSION_ALOC = -1, E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR = -2, E_SFTP_ALLOC = -3, E_INIT_SFTP = -4, E_CREATE_DIR = -5, E_FILEOPEN_WRITE = -6, E_WRITE_ERR = -7
    , E_FILE_CLOSE = -8, E_FILE_OPEN_READ = -9, E_INVALID_PARAMS = -10, E_SFTP_ERR = -11, E_SFTP_READ_ERR = -12, E_SFTP_READBYTES_ERR = -13, E_GET_FILEINF = -14
    , E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND = -15, E_RENAME_ERR = -16, E_MEM_ALLOC = -17, E_LOCAL_FILE_READ = -18, E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR = -19, E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK = -20
    , E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN = -21, E_DELETE_ERR = -22, E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE = -23, E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE = -24, E_FILEOPEN_RDONLY = -25, E_SFTP_READ_EOF=-26
                        ,E_UNKNOWN=-999 } ESSHERR;


// status of transfers;
typedef enum sftpstat{ ES_DONE=0 , ES_INPROGRESS , ES_FAILED, ES_STARTING, ES_PAUSED, ES_RESUMING, ES_CANCELLED,  ES_NONE  } ESFTPSTAT;

using namespace std;


// statistics about the transfer;
typedef struct transferstatstruct {
    string remote_file_name;
    string local_file_name;
    __int64  total_size;
    __int64  transferred;
    __int64  averagebps;
    long long   seconds_elapsed;
    long long       seconds_remained;
    int percent;
    ESFTPSTAT transferstate;
} TTransStat;


#define E_SESSION_NEW   -1



// these libraries are required
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")





// this is the main class that does the majority of the work

typedef class CSFTPConnector{

private:

    ssh_session  session;                 // ssh session
    sftp_session sftp;                      // sftp session
    sftp_file file;                         // structure for a remote file
    FILE *localfile;                        // not used in windows but could be local file pointer in UNIX
    FILE *logfile;                          // the file for writing logs, default is set to stderr
    string filename;                        // file name of the transfer;
    string localfilename;                   // file name of local file;
    string      tempfilename;               // a temporaty file name will be used during the transfer which is renamed when transfer is completed.
    ESFTPSTAT transferstatus;               // state of the transfer which has one of the above values (ESFTPSTAT)
    time_t  transferstarttime;              // time of start of the transfer
    wchar_t username[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t password[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    wchar_t hostname[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];       // hostname of the sftp server
    wchar_t basedir[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];        // this base dir is the directory of public and private key structur ( NOT USED IN THIS VERSION)
    int port;                               //  port of the server;
    int verbosity;                          //  degree of verbosity of libssh
    __int64  filesize;                      //  total number of bytes to be transfered;
    DWORD  local_file_size_hiDWORD;         //  Bill Gates cannot accept the file size without twisting the programmers, so he accepts them in 2 separate words like this
    DWORD  local_file_size_lowDWORD;        //  these 2 DWORDs when connected together comprise a 64 bit file size.
    __int64 lfilesize;                          // local file size
    __int64 rfilesize;                          // remote file size
    __int64 transfered;                         // number of bytes already transfered
    bool pause;                                 // pause flag
    TTransStat stats;                           // statistics of the transfer
    HANDLE  localfilehandle;                    // windows uses handles to manipulate files. this is the handle to local file.

    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rwopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read/write   for upload
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rdopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn);         // open a file on remote ( server ) read only    for download
    ESSHERR createSFTPfile(char *fn);                                   // create a file on server;
    ESSHERR writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize);               // write a block of data to the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, size_t len, size_t *bytesread);   // read a block of data from the  open remote file
    ESSHERR readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread);
    ESSHERR closeSFTPfile();        // closes the remote file;
    ESSHERR openSFTPfile(char *fn);  // opens the remote file
    ESSHERR getSFTPfileinfo();          // gets information about the remote file


public:
    wstring errstring;      // the string describing last error 
    ESSHERR Err;                // error code of last error
    CSFTPConnector();           // default constructor;
    CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass);  // constructor
    void setVerbosity(int v);       
    int  getVerbosity();
    ESSHERR InitSession();          // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR ConnectSession();       // connnects to the  ssh server
    ESSHERR InitSFTP();     // must be called befor doing any transfer
    ESSHERR Makedir(char *newdir);
    ESSHERR testUploadFile(char *fn, char *block);          // do not use this , only for test purposes for myself
    ESSHERR SFTPput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);            // Upload a file from start
    ESSHERR SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);          // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (UPLOAD)
    ESSHERR SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname);                   // renames a remote file( must be closed)
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile);                  // deletes a remote file
    TTransStat getStatus();                                             // gets statistics of the transfer
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);    // Downloads a file from  sftp server
    ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize);  // checks for previouse interrupted transfer, then either continues the previouse transfer ( if there was any) or starts a new one (DOWNLOAD)
    void    CancelTransfer();
    void    PauseTransfer();
    void    setLogFile(FILE *logf);         // sets the log file, if not set stderr will be used. by default.
    void    CloseLocalFile();
    void    CloseRemoteFile();

    ~CSFTPConnector();




} SFTPConnector, *pSFTPConnector ;





void    CSFTPConnector::CloseLocalFile()
{
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CloseRemoteFile()
{
    sftp_close(file);
}



void    CSFTPConnector::setLogFile(FILE *logf)
{
    logfile = logf;
}


void    CSFTPConnector::CancelTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_CANCELLED;

}
void    CSFTPConnector::PauseTransfer()
{
    transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
    pause = true;
}

//----------------------------------------


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPget(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    DWORD       result;
    int rc;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;

    filename = rfn;

    tempfilename = string(lfn) + ".sftp_temp";
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, tempfilename.c_str(), SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open local file:" + wstring(temp) + L" for read and write";
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
    }

    lfilesize =0;
    transfered =0;

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }

    result = rdopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)rfn);

    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        filesize = rfilesize;
    }
    else
    {
        Err = E_REMOTE_FILE_OPEN;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not open remote file";
        CloseLocalFile();
        delete block;
        return E_REMOTEFILE_SEEK;
    }


    transferstatus = ES_STARTING;

    sftp_file_set_blocking(file);
    transferstarttime = time(NULL);
    transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED &&  transferstatus != ES_CANCELLED  &&transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;

        result = readSFTPfile(block, blocksize, (size_t *)&bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && result!= E_SFTP_READ_EOF )
        {
            errstring = L"Error reading from remote sftp server file.";
            Err = (ESSHERR)result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            delete block;
            return (ESSHERR)result;
        }
        if (result == E_SFTP_READ_EOF)  transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);

        bresult = WriteFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, bytesread, &bytesread, NULL);
        if (bytesread < blocksize)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error writing to local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                delete block;
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_RDWR;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }


        Err = E_OK;

        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);

    }

    // closing files
    result = closeSFTPfile();
    CloseHandle(localfilehandle);

    Sleep(1000);


    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = MoveFile(temp, temp2);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_RENAME_LOCAL_FILE;
        }
    }

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        wchar_t temp2[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
        mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp2, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
        bresult = DeleteFile(temp);
        if (bresult != TRUE)
        {
            Err = E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
            errstring = L"Could not rename local file: " + wstring(temp);
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            delete block;
            return E_LOCAL_DELETE_FILE;
        }
    }

    delete block;
    return (ESSHERR) result;
}


TTransStat CSFTPConnector::getStatus()
{
    stats.seconds_elapsed = time(NULL) - transferstarttime;
    stats.averagebps = (transfered * 8) / stats.seconds_elapsed;
    if (filesize > 0) {
        stats.percent = (transfered *100)/ filesize;
        stats.seconds_remained = ((filesize - transfered) * 8) / stats.averagebps;
    }
    else
    {
        stats.percent = -1;
        stats.seconds_remained = -1;
    }
    stats.total_size = filesize;
    stats.transferstate = transferstatus;
    stats.remote_file_name = filename;
    stats.local_file_name = localfilename;

    return stats;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPrename(char *newname, char *oldname)
{

    int rc=sftp_rename(sftp, oldname, newname);
    if (rc !=SSH_OK){
        return E_RENAME_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}



ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPdelete(char *remfile)
{

    int rc = sftp_unlink(sftp,remfile);
    if (rc != SSH_OK){
        return E_DELETE_ERR;
    }

    return E_OK;
}



ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::SFTPreput(char *lfn, char *rfn, size_t blocksize)
{
    ESSHERR     result;
    BOOL  bresult;
    DWORD bytesread;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    char *block;
    struct stat st;
    wchar_t temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t tempsize;
    wstring wlfn;
    int loopcounter = 0;

    localfilename = lfn;
    //wlfn = wstring(lfn);
    //localfile = fopen(lfn, L"r");
    filename = rfn;
    mbstowcs_s(&tempsize, temp, lfn, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);

    //filesize = getFileSize(localfilename);

    /*if(filesize < 0) {
    transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
    Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }*/

    localfilehandle = CreateFile(temp, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (localfilehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }
    local_file_size_lowDWORD = GetFileSize(localfilehandle, &local_file_size_hiDWORD);
    filesize = (local_file_size_hiDWORD * 0x100000000) + local_file_size_lowDWORD;

    if (filesize < 0) {
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_LOCAL_FILE_NOTFOUND;
    }

    block = (char*)malloc(blocksize + 1);
    if (block == NULL) {
        Err = E_MEM_ALLOC;
        transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate memory for file block size";
        CloseLocalFile();
        return E_MEM_ALLOC;
    }


    tempfilename = string(rfn) + ".sftp_temp";

    result = rwopen_existing_SFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    if (result == E_OK){
        getSFTPfileinfo();
        sftp_seek64(file, rfilesize);
        __int64 tempi64 = rfilesize & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
        DWORD dwlow = tempi64;
        tempi64 = (rfilesize & 0x7FFFFFFF00000000);
        tempi64 = tempi64 >> 32;
        long  dwhi = tempi64;
        DWORD dwResult=SetFilePointer(localfilehandle, dwlow,&dwhi , FILE_BEGIN);
        if (dwResult == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
        {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; Err = result;  return result;
        }
        transferstatus = ES_RESUMING;
        transfered = rfilesize;

    }
    else{
        result = createSFTPfile((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        transferstatus = ES_STARTING;
        if (result != E_OK)  {
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED; 
            Err = result;
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }
        }
        sftp_file_set_blocking(file);
        transferstarttime = time(NULL);
        transferstatus = ES_INPROGRESS;

    while (transferstatus != ES_FAILED && transferstatus != ES_PAUSED && transferstatus != ES_DONE)
    {
        loopcounter++;
        bresult = ReadFile(localfilehandle, (LPVOID)block, blocksize, &bytesread, NULL);
        fprintf(logfile, "Read %d bytes from input file. Number of packets: %d , %llu from %llu bytes\n", bytesread, loopcounter, transfered, filesize);
        if (bytesread < blocksize)
        {
            if (bresult == FALSE)
            {
                errstring = L"Error reading from local file.";
                Err = E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
                transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
                CloseRemoteFile();
                CloseLocalFile();
                return E_LOCAL_FILE_READ;
            }
            else if (bytesread == 0)
            {
                errstring = L"Transfer done.";
                Err = E_OK;
                transferstatus = ES_DONE;
                continue;
            }
        }

        result = writeSFTPfile(block, bytesread);
        if (result != E_OK && bytesread>0 )
        {
            errstring = L"Error transmitting to remote sftp server file.";
            Err = result;
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            CloseRemoteFile();
            CloseLocalFile();
            return result;
        }


        Err = E_OK;
        //transfered = transfered + bytesread;
        if (pause == true) transferstatus = ES_PAUSED;
        if (bresult == TRUE &&  bytesread == 0)
        {
            // at the end of the file
            transferstatus = ES_DONE;
        }
        Sleep(BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 331 == 0)Sleep(77 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);
        if (loopcounter % 3331 == 0)Sleep(777 * BLOCKTRANSDELAY);

    }

    CloseRemoteFile();
    CloseLocalFile();
    Sleep(1000);

    if (transferstatus == ES_CANCELLED)
    {
        result = SFTPdelete((char *)tempfilename.c_str());
        if (bresult != E_OK)
        {
            Err = E_DELETE_ERR;
            errstring = L"Could not delete remote file.";
            transferstatus = ES_FAILED;
            return E_DELETE_ERR;
        }
    }
    if (transferstatus == ES_DONE) result = SFTPrename(rfn, (char *)tempfilename.c_str());
    delete block;
    return result;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::getSFTPfileinfo()
{
    sftp_attributes fileinf = sftp_fstat(file);

    if (fileinf == NULL){
        return E_GET_FILEINF;
    }

    rfilesize = fileinf->size;

    sftp_attributes_free(fileinf);
    return E_OK;
}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::closeSFTPfile()
{
    int rc = sftp_close(file);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't close the written file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_CLOSE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::writeSFTPfile(char *block, size_t blocksize)
{
    size_t nwritten = sftp_write(file, block, blocksize);
    if (nwritten != blocksize)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't write data to file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        //sftp_close(file);
        transfered = transfered + nwritten;
        return E_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    transfered = transfered + nwritten;
    return E_OK;
}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::readSFTPfile(char *block, size_t len, size_t *bytesread)
{

    DWORD readbytes;
    *bytesread = 0;
    if (len <= 0) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;
    if (bytesread == NULL || block == NULL) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;

    readbytes = sftp_read(file, block, len);
    if (readbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't read  from  remote file: %s  %s\n", filename.c_str(), ssh_get_error(session));
        *bytesread = 0;
        return E_SFTP_READ_ERR;
    }


    if (readbytes <  len)
    {
        *bytesread = readbytes;
        transfered = transfered + readbytes;
        return E_SFTP_READ_EOF;
    }


    *bytesread = readbytes;
    transfered = transfered + readbytes;

    return E_OK;

}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::readSFTPfile(char *block, __int64 len, DWORD *bytesread)
{
    DWORD readbytes;
    *bytesread = 0;
    if (len <= 0) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;
    if (bytesread == NULL || block == NULL) return E_INVALID_PARAMS;

    readbytes = sftp_read(file, block, len);
    if (readbytes < 0)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't read  from  remote file: %s  %s\n", filename.c_str(), ssh_get_error(session));
        *bytesread = 0;
        return E_SFTP_READ_ERR;
    }


    if (readbytes <  len)
    {
        *bytesread = readbytes;
        return E_SFTP_READ_EOF;
    }


    *bytesread = readbytes;
    transfered = transfered + readbytes;

    return E_OK;

}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::createSFTPfile(char *fn)
{

    int access_type = O_CREAT | O_RDWR;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILEOPEN_WRITE;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::rdopen_existing_SFTPfile(char *fn)
{

    int access_type = O_RDONLY ;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IREAD);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILEOPEN_RDONLY;
    }
    return E_OK;
}




ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::openSFTPfile(char *fn)
{
    int access_type = O_RDONLY;
    int rc, nwritten;

    filename = string(fn);
    file = sftp_open(sftp, fn,
        access_type, S_IWRITE);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return E_FILE_OPEN_READ;
    }
    return E_OK;

}

ESSHERR CSFTPConnector::Makedir(char *newdir)
{
    int rc;
    rc = sftp_mkdir(sftp, newdir, S_IFDIR);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        if (sftp_get_error(sftp) != SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            fprintf(logfile, "Can't create directory: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(session));
            return E_CREATE_DIR;
        }
    }

        return E_OK;
}




SFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector()
{
    //libssh2_init(0);
    session = ssh_new();
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, L"localhost" );
    wcscpy(username, L"User");
    wcscpy(password, L"Password");
    wcscpy(basedir, L".\\");
    port = 22;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
    filesize = 0;
    transfered = 0;

    pause = false;
    transferstatus = ES_NONE;
    logfile = stderr;
}


CSFTPConnector::CSFTPConnector(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *hn, int hostport, wchar_t *un, wchar_t *pass)
{

    session = ssh_new();

    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SESSION_ALOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a session.";

    }
    wcscpy(hostname, hn);
    wcscpy(username, un);
    wcscpy(password, pass);
    wcscpy(basedir, dir);
    port = hostport;
    verbosity = SSH_LOG_RARE;
     filesize=0;
     transfered=0;

     pause=false;
     transferstatus = ES_NONE;
     logfile = stderr;

}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSFTP()
{
    int rc;
    sftp= sftp_new(session);
    if (session == NULL)
    {
        Err = E_SFTP_ALLOC;
        errstring = L"Could not allocate a sftp session.";

    }

    rc = sftp_init(sftp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(logfile, "Error initializing SFTP session: %s.\n",
            sftp_get_error(sftp));
        sftp_free(sftp);
        return E_INIT_SFTP;
    }


    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::ConnectSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)password, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    int ir;

    ir=ssh_connect(session);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not connect the ssh session.";
        return E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR;
    }

    ir=ssh_userauth_password(session, NULL, temp);
    if (ir != SSH_OK){
        errstring = L"Could not connect the ssh session.";
        return E_SSH_CONNECT_ERR;
    }
    return E_OK;
}


ESSHERR  CSFTPConnector::InitSession()
{
    char temp[SHORT_BUFF_LEN];
    size_t n_of_chars;
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp,SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *) hostname, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,temp);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)username, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER,temp);
    wcstombs_s(&n_of_chars, temp, SHORT_BUFF_LEN, (const wchar_t *)basedir, SHORT_BUFF_LEN);
    ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_SSH_DIR, temp);

    return E_OK;
}


CSFTPConnector::~CSFTPConnector()
{


    sftp_free(sftp);
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_free(session);

    return;
}
```